# Is there any way to make separate main.xml for tablet?

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I have developed an app with 6 panels for android phones. Now I would like to support android tablets too. I think I'd just show UIs of the 6 panels in a big screen of the tablet. Is there any way to have separate xml for the layout of tablet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have separate layouts for different screen sizes. See the guide topic [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

The basic technique prior to 3.2 is to create a resource directory `layout-xlarge` and put your tablet-specific layouts there. The xml files in that directory should have the same names as the files in the regular `layout` directory.

For OS 3.2, things have changed quite a bit. Take a look at the section [Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).